# calling only subsets of a role?

Tags: ansible

```
inventories/
   production/
      hosts.yml           # inventory file for production servers
      group_vars/         # contains global variables for microservices

webservers.yml      

roles/
    webservers/
      tasks/              
        main.yml          # has include statements for all the other files in tasks
        microservice1.yml
        microservice2.yml
        install_certificates.yml
        etc
    vars/                 # contains variables for each microservice
```

That is my current directory structure. Initially I set it up so that the webservers.yml playbook will fully deploy a newly provisioned web server...so install apache, php, certs, and all the microservice sites.

What I am wondering is, what is the best way to accomplish running only subsets of the webservers role? Like if I only want to run the microservice1.yml tasks and nothing else. Is that doable with the current inventory structure or do I need to make each task it's own role and include them all in webservers.yml? Which way would be considered better practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and intended way to accomplish this is to use tags. You add the same tag to the rules you want to group together, and then you run ansible so that it executes only the rules tagged that way.

For example, this rule is tagged with "usersetup"

```
- name: Create user groups
  group: name={{ item.username }} state=present
  with_items: "{{ my_items }}"
  tags: [ "usersetup" ]
```

If you run your playbook like this:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts --ask-become-pass site.yml --tags usersetup`

only rules tagged with usersetup will be executed. Note that you can add multiple tags to a rule, by separating them with commas.

Comment: So I guess I just gotta decide then whether I prefer the tags or individual roles. Thanks.